# Using iPython with nose?

Tags: python, ipython, nose, pdb

I have a fairly basic question. I'm running the `nosetests` command for my python application's test suite. I want to drop into an interactive debugger. As the tests are run, it hits my `IPython.embed()` line and freezes, no prompt. Ctrl+C kills it and resumes the tests.

How can I drop into an interactive prompt of some sort while running nosetests?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely nose captures stdout. If you can run it with -s option it should work as expected. You can also use `from nose.tools import set_trace; set_trace()` to use pdb debugger, it will pass stdout/stdin properly.